# valgrind not catching obvious lost memory

Tags: c, memory, valgrind

I've used valgrind before and it has been very helpful.  I recently setup a dev environment and starting using valgrind again.  This time it finds NO lost memory!  Even if I malloc some memory and then interrupt the program with CTRL-C, I get the dump below.  Can someone explain what's going on?

Confused....

```
==2489== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2489==     in use at exit: 314,145 bytes in 585 blocks
==2489==   total heap usage: 1,410 allocs, 825 frees, 2,025,829 bytes allocated
==2489== 
==2489== LEAK SUMMARY:
==2489==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2489==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2489==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2489==    still reachable: 314,145 bytes in 585 blocks
==2489==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2489== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==2489== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes
==2489== 
==2489== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==2489== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 6)
```

Comment: Memory isn't lost if the program terminates and you still have a pointer to it. It's shown under "still reachable," because it was still reachable at the end of your program.

Comment: ctrl+c sends a SIGINT which basically interrupts your program from continuing execution. That's why you're getting the "still reachable" because all that memory has been allocated but not freed. if you use the flags valgrind suggests, mainly `--show-reachable=yes`, then it'll give the locations where.

Comment: @BlackJack: Please as that as an answer & I will upvote it,that explains it better than any of the ones already present.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there is still a pointer to the `malloc`ed memory, it's not a leak. It's showing up as *still reachable* in the summary.

Memory that is not `free`ed is not necessarily leaked if it's still live, that is, there's still a pointer to it somewhere (globally, from the stack, or from registers.)